# Multiple objects override previous objects data

Tags: object

When I instantiate multiple objects, the newer objects override the properties of the older objects, for example:

```
object1.color = red;
object2.color = yellow;
object3.color = green;
object4.color = blue;
```

If I try to return `object1.color`, then it will return blue. Is there a way around this? I have been told that the only way to do it, is to set the value again every time.

Comment: What language is this?
What is the expected output?

Comment: this is just a model of the concept, not actual code. but im using java. and the expected output would be red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you wouldn't experience this issue, unless we are talking about static class fields:

```java
public class Program
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Foo object1 = new Foo();
    Foo object2 = new Foo();

    object1.instanceColor = "red";
    object2.instanceColor = "green";

    object1.staticColor = "red";
    object2.staticColor = "green";

    System.out.println(object1.staticColor);
    System.out.println(object2.staticColor);
    // output is "green green"

    System.out.println(object1.instanceColor);
    System.out.println(object2.instanceColor);
    // output is "red green"
  }
}


public class Foo
{
  public static String staticColor;
  public String instanceColor;

  public Foo() {}
}
```

Static fields would indeed be shared between all instances of the class.

Instance fields, however, belong to the instances and do not affect each other.